# How to place 3 consecutive cell data in top 3 cells of a column

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, copy, cell

I am using Mobile version of Excel. I need a formula which does the following...

In an excel column, select top 3 cells that read in set of 3 consecutive cell entries appearing in the same column anywhere.

I have started with "if" condition that unselects the blanks. Next it just copies the value from the cell just below it. Obviously it doesn't work.

I have been suggested following formula but its not returning what I need...

```
=IF(ROW(A1)<=COUNTA(A:A)-2, INDEX(A:A, ROW(A1)) & ", " & INDEX(A:A, ROW(A1)+1) & ", " & INDEX(A:A, ROW(A1)+2), "")
```

Comment: Post few sample data then show your desired output.

Comment: Why present the function twice? What does not work with that function or is it you just don’t understand it?

Comment: @SolarMike     
Question is self explanatory ... However, the formula given to me just doesn't work. Secondly, for clarity, lets assume we have three values at A10, A11 and A12 as 34, 35 and 45 respectively. All cells above and below these entries are empty. We just need top 3 cells to get filled with these values i.e. A1, A2, A3 having 34, 35 and 45 respectively.

Comment: Then explain it.

Comment: @SolarMike     
... Explain what !

Comment: @Harun24hr     
Kindly guide me how put excel snapshot here

Comment: @RehanKhan Read this article. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344851/5514747

Comment: So it doesn't need to be consecutive, but just the first three non blanks from the top? `=take(Tocol(a1:a99,1),3)` or `=take(filter(A1:a99,a1:a99<>""),3)`

Answer (score 3):

### First (Top-Most) 3 Consecutive Non-Blank Cells in Column

[image]

```
=LET(Data,A4:A20,
    ff,Data<>"",mf,VSTACK(DROP(ff,1),0),lf,VSTACK(DROP(mf,1),0),
IFERROR(INDEX(Data,SEQUENCE(3,,XMATCH(1,ff*mf*lf))),""))
```

**Edit**

Reading the comment you posted

> *"... lets assume we have three values at A10, A11 and A12 as 34, 35 and 45 respectively. All cells above and below these entries are
> empty. We just need top 3 cells to get filled with these values i.e.
> A1, A2, A3 having 34, 35 and 45 respectively."*

the following simplification might be considered:

```
=LET(Data,A4:A20,
IFERROR(INDEX(Data,SEQUENCE(3,,XMATCH(TRUE,Data<>""))),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Creative approach. I wonder if it's what's required, but I like it anyway.

Comment: Thanks indeed. 
Now the same is required for row as was for column ...